# How to Map the method having interface and class -- from action to delegate

Tags: java

Consider a method in delegate

```
Public void findThisMethod(String a,Set b,HashSet c){}
```

So from action am gng to map this method with method id and argument types..by using.

```
Object[] arguments = new Object[] {a,b,c}
    for (int i = 0 ; i < arguments.length ; i++){
      argumentTypes[i]  = arguments[i].getClass();
    }
Method invokeMethod = delegateClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodID,argumentTypes);
returnObj           = invokeMethod.invoke(delegateObj,arguments);
```

...Issue:: This s not wotking Since Set is an interface!!! Can any one plz tell me how to map the interface correctly????

Comment: As explained in your other question, you *can't* do this just from argument values. If you can get *all* declared methods, you can at least find *compatible* methods, but that's not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the signature of a method using getDeclaredMethod, then you should provide the exact types of the pameters of this signature, not subclasses. Subclassing will be resolved by the compiler, but it doesn't help in introspection.

Provide explicitely the types of the parameters, don't get them from objects as you do it. You should have something like

```
delegateClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodID, new Class[] { String.class, Set.class, HashSet.class } );
```

Comment: Hi.. Consider am having Set b... is it possible to find the reverse process.. ie.. wat is the type of b... ex.. for String a we can get from a.getClass(). is ter any way to find the interface,,

Comment: You can retrieve the method by recursively trying all supertypes and interfaces implemented by your objects but this is a greedy process

Comment: oh.. So sad.. So, its not possible to find the type of the interface?

Comment: Sure you can http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces()

Comment: But what I mean is that you will have to search through all inherited interfaces and supertypes to achieve what you want and find an interesting signature.

Answer (score 1):

In general you need to spend the same effort like the compiler when it tries to choose the best overloading method for a method call.

In your case, you have to test, if a method exists for the given arguments `a, b, c`. If not, then you have to look at the supertypes and interfaces.

You may be able to do it vice versa: get the set of available methods and create a prioritised list of candidate methods for the argument vector.

Answer (score 1):

Examples how to find compatible methods:

[primer 1](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1329/)

[primer2](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Development/BasicallyClassgetMethodbutallowsforalistofparametertypesinsteadofavariableargumentslist.htm)